# how to enclose variable in single quote php

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I want to enclose `PHP` variable in single quote because, I can not access double quoted variables in my `JQUERY` plugin (`X-Editable`)

**PHP**

```
$countries = array();
foreach($countries as $c){
    $country_id = $c['country_id'];
    $short_name = $c['short_name'];
    array_push($countries, array('value' => '$country_id', 'text' => '$short_name'));    <-- I want something like this...
}
```

I can not use:

```
array('value' => $country_id, 'text' => $short_name) OR
array('value' => "$country_id", 'text' => "$short_name")
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#cus_country').editable({
type: 'select',
pk: '1',
url: '/user/inline_edit',
title: 'Enter Country',
source: '<?=json_encode($countries)?>',
display: function(value) {
    if (value !== "Add Country"){
         $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>' + value);
     }
    },
success: function(response, newValue) {
    //alert(response);
    if(response.status == 'error') return response.msg;
}
});
```

**EDIT**
When I use as static values it comes in dropdown menu without any error. But when I put variable in array then there is a problem.

For example:

```
CASE # 1
$countries = array('value'=>'some', 'text'=>'thing');
output of this variable:
Array([0]=>Array([value]=>some [text]=>thing))

CASE # 2
$countries = array('value'=>$some, 'text'=>$thing);
output of this variable:
Array([0]=>Array([value]=>some [text]=>thing))
```

As you can see, both of the cases are giving me same output. But, first case generates the dropdown and second not.

Comment: If you can't access variables in jQuery using double quotes, try escaping them instead. You'd have to tell us which one you're trying to use quotes for.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : Can you elaborate please? I don't know about escaping.

Comment: Something like `\"$var\"`

Comment: ok.. I see. But, I need array strictly some thing like this: `array('value' => 'value1', 'text' => 'value2')`

Comment: See the answer below then. I didn't know which variable you were asking about.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, the keys and the values are strings regardless how you set them and they get double quotes as soon as you `json_encode()` them. You probably should not be quoting your `source` value with single quotes, that is likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you are echo'ing your json encode inside of a string like `source: '<?=json_encode($countries)?>',`? That is then just a string, not an object which is what most plugins like this would need like `source: <?=json_encode($countries)?>,`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : Can you check my edit please?

Comment: What is the problem you are getting when using the variables? Because there should be nothing wrong with that unless your variable isn't defined or somewhere you have like a blank value/text. Actually use the variables, view the source of the page to see if the json echo looks good and also open developer tools and watch the console while you refresh the page to see if there is a javascript error.

Comment: oh.. When I use variable, then it says: `SyntaxError: missing } after property list` in console output.. What's that? Because, I am not changing javascript code at all in both of the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

It was incorrect form of variable. In database, variables were stored in this format: `People's thing`, etc.

Thanks to @jonathan Kuhn for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_push($countries, array('value' => "'.$country_id.'", 'text' => '$short_name'));
```

You have to use the . . syntax in php to define where to derefence a variable.  By using `'$test'`, you are you not using the variable, but a string with a dollar sign and the letters test.